# How to find the percentage of missing dates by group in Snowflake table?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with multiple groups that cover a diverse time range, like the table below.

| ACCOUNT | CREATION_DATE |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2021-01-01 |
| A | 2021-01-02 |
| A | 2021-01-04 |
| A | 2021-01-05 |
| ... | ... |
| B | 2021-02-02 |
| B | 2021-02-06 |
| B | 2021-02-07 |

The groups do not have the same start and end date.

I'd like to determine the fraction of missing dates between each group's start and end date for each group. How can I do this using Snowflake SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using COUNT and DATEDIFF(day, min_date, max_date):

```
SELECT ACCOUNT, 
  100.0 * COUNT(DISTINCT CREATION_DATE)/
    NULLIF(DATEDIFF('DAY', MIN(CREATION_DATE), MAX(CREATION_DATE))+1,0) 
    AS mising_dates_percentage
FROM tab
GROUP BY ACCOUNT
```

Comment: Beautiful, thank you! The only adjustment I needed to make was to add `+1` to `MAX(CREATION_DATE)` to be inclusive of that date in the denominator. Otherwise brilliant!

Comment: Also this query returns the percentage of dates that ARE represented in the data, which works for me, but the column name `missing_dates` is a misnomer.